# Election page voter count bug

Tags: bug, user-interface, moderator-tools, election

From the [Academia.SE election page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election): (only moderators of the site can see this)

> [image]

Fairly sure we've had more than zero visitors since we started the election...

Comment: Wait... where do you see this? Visited the page now, no such information in there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard He's a pro-tem moderator on Academia, so he can see that box before the election completes.

Comment: Strictly speaking the actual *election* doesn't start for another four days, but I forget if that's the issue here or not.

Comment: @Tim cool, didn't notice. Added to the post to prevent others from getting confused.

Comment: I think @TimStone is right. That only counts visitors during the actual *election* phase, not the nomination and primary periods. Just like the Constituent badge is for voting in the actual *election* phase.

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. Didn't realize I have special access to that due to diamond status. That makes it a lot less high priority.

Comment: @eykanal so maybe feature request is due, to make it more clear it's a moderator power... until then, you can browse those pages as anonymous visitor or even create new account for this purpose.